# Nativescript app getting crashed on Redmi 1S

Tags: android, nativescript

I have created the Grocery test app on Nativescript platform but when i tried to launch it on Redmi 1S, the app gets crashed while launching.

This is the log:

```
W/dalvikvm( 4854):in Lcom/tns/Runtime;.callJSMethodNative(IILjava/lang/String;IZ[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (CallIntMethodA)
I/dalvikvm( 4854):   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm( 4854):   at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1022)
I/dalvikvm( 4854):   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:907)
I/dalvikvm( 4854):   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:895)
I/dalvikvm( 4854):   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:879)
I/dalvikvm( 4854):   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:871)
```

Comment: Same issue. I extracted login module from sample-grocery demo and using in my app. Testing on LG G3 with Android version 6.0.
```
12-28 18:35:39.065  8782  8782 W System.err:  at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
12-28 18:35:39.065  8782  8782 W System.err:  at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1022)
12-28 18:35:39.065  8782  8782 W System.err:  at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:907)
12-28 18:35:39.065  8782  8782 W System.err:  at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:895)
...
```
Have you considered opening issue on github?

Comment: Salomon - I just removed this code from login method of login.component  and this eliminated the error:
`
        if (getConnectionType() === connectionType.none) {
            alert("Internet connection required to log in.");
            return;
        }
`